# char replacement methods

Tags: java

may i ask what is the alternative function for the replace() method in java? since the replace method will replace the old char to a new char but my code is like hangman which initially you have _ _ _ _ _ and when i use replace() instead of replacing a specific charAt() like charAt(2) = 'A', it will replace all the _ with A. any suggestions on what is the alternative for replacing a specific character? thank you

here is my code fragment.

```
  guessLetter = txtguesswordS.getText().toString();

    char letter = guessLetter.charAt(0);

  int indx = word.indexOf(letter);

  public void convertUnderscore(String word){
        for(int x = 0;x<word.length();x++){
             Uscore += "-";
         }

 public void replaceLetter(char letter, int indx){
         char oldLetter;
         oldLetter = Uscore.charAt(indx);
         update = Uscore.replace(oldLetter, letter);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `StringBuilder`, which you should generally use when you want a "modifiable `String`", then you can just use [`StringBuilder.setCharAt(int, char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt%28int,%20char%29).  You can convert a `StringBuilder` to a `String` with its `toString()` method.